# gitpython open a repository from somwhere within the repository

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Within a python script which I would like to be able to execute from some arbitrary location within a git repositories working tree, in some arbitrary git repository, and I would like to use GitPython to extract some information about said repository.

I can get the information I need from the Repo object, but I can't figure out how to open a Repo object , but the Repo constructor requires a path to repo-root.

Is there a way to construct a Repo object with a path to somewhere in the repo, not just the repo-root location?  Alternatively is there a way to query the location of repo root for a given path?

I'm looking for something like:

```
import git
r = git.Repo('whatever repo the cwd is in')
```

The following works, but I find it hopelessly clunky:

```
import git
import subprocess

rtpath = subprocess.check_output(["git", "rev-parse", "--show-toplevel"])
repo = git.Repo(rtpath.strip())
```

Comment: Please rephrase what you're trying to do, and where you get stuck. Currently your problem is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to implement the same search semantics that `git` implements internally...e.g., look for `.git` directory, if it doesn't exist, `chdir` up one level, check again, etc.  Something like:

```
import os
import git

lastcwd=os.getcwd()
while not os.path.isdir('.git'):
    os.chdir('..')
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    if cwd == lastcwd:
        raise OSError('no .git directory')
    lastcwd=cwd

r = git.Repo('.')
```

The above code is simplistic; for example, `git` won't traverse over a filesystem boundary in it's default configuration, while the above code will always iterate all the way up to `/`.